# What is wrong with this dbDelta syntax?

Tags: plugins, functions, dbdelta

I know there's a million questions about this, but I've searched a bunch and haven't found any solutions that fix my problem.

This is the function which I hook upon plugin activation:

```
global $wpdb;
$src = $wpdb->prefix . "source";
$via = $wpdb->prefix . "via";
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
$query = "CREATE TABLE " . $src . "(
        source_index bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    post_id bigint,
                    source_id int,
                    source varchar(100),
                    source_title varchar(100),
                    PRIMARY KEY  (source_index)
            );";
    dbDelta($query);
$query = "CREATE TABLE " . $via . "(
        via_index bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    post_id bigint,
                    via_id int,
                    via varchar(100),
                    via_title varchar(100),
                    PRIMARY KEY  (via_index)
            );";
    dbDelta($query);
```

It does nothing at all, and I don't understand why. I thought for certain that I'd corrected all issues.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you test your generated SQL separately? Does it matter if you add a single space between the table name and the parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

The `dbDelta` function is **super** nitpicky. Everything has to be exactly correct.

In this case, the lack of space between the table name and the parentheses following it will cause your call to fail, because it can't figure out the table name without that space.

The relevant code in `dbDelta()` is this:

`if (preg_match("|CREATE TABLE ([^ ]*)|", $qry, $matches)) {`

It's looking for CREATE TABLE, followed by a space, followed by some text that does not contain a space. That ending space between the table name and the open-parenth is therefore not optional.